# Как сделать из асинхронного итератора обычный

Tags: python, async-await, asyncio

У меня асинхронная программа, в ней есть очередь, куда я кладу обработанные результаты

```
queue = asyncio.Queue(2<<10)
```

Пока вот таким генератором данные забираю

```
def get_records(queue):
    while queue.qsize():
        r = queue.get_nowait()
        yield r
        self.q.task_done()
```

Но из-за того что он сейчас быстро заканчивается приходится переподключаться к базе:

```
        while True:
             async with pg.acquire() as connection:
                 await connection.copy_records_to_table(
                     'radarlog2',
                     records = get_records(queue)
                 )
             await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Где pg это пут asyncpg. Где-то в недрах copy_records_to_table есть поддержка асинхронного итератора, но до него не доходит с ошибной что он не итерируемый.

Как бы сделать  `await queue.get()` не блокируя евент луп?

- loop.run_until_complete не работает с запущенным лупом
- asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe блокирует
- asgiref/sync стартует новые треды и весьма громоздкая конструкция

Comment: Судя по коду asyncpg, из всего records собирается единый буфер данных, так что асинхронный итератор здесь в принципе не имеет смысла...

Comment: https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/blob/690048dbaaebac6172f003a9805bbb63abd28d8c/asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx#L439 - хоть буфер и собирается, но может отправляться внутри цикла при размере больше 524288. этот размер соберется за пару секунд если бы итератор не блокировался

Comment: наверное ищю аналог  QCoreApplication::processEvents()

Answer (score 0):

На сам вопрос пока ответа нет, но по конкретному примеру. Если собрать стек вызово вручную до https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/blob/690048dbaaebac6172f003a9805bbb63abd28d8c/asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx#L461 , то через ридер получится то что нужно. Но слишком много мелкой копипасты.